# babel transpile incomplete?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

My page is rendering with the following javascript:

```
<script src="/static/js/index.js" type="text/javascript">
'use strict';
//modules/index.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
ReactDOM.render(
React.createElement(
'div',
null,
'hello world!'
), document.getElementById('content'));
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
</script>
```

Which my browser can't make any sense of, because it doesn't know what React is... because there's no includes anywhere. Even after I include react js files (e.g. from cdn) my browser js console reports

```
'ReferenceError:require is not defined'.
```

After installing tons of babel and react related modules, why does the transpiler still produce output that makes no sense to the browser? My .babelrc presets are ["es2015","react"]. In my package.json file is:

```
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "babel -w modules/ -d public/js --source-maps && exit code 0",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you installed Node?

Comment: @AndrewL. I have node, babel-*, pug, react-*. That's my frustration. So many things to install and yet none of them detect and work with each other :-(

Comment: So where did you get that html from?

Comment: I have an index.pug. In it, it has script tags to load my babelfied .js file.  the node app comes up just fine, and is completely blank, because the react components don't render. I added the reactjs and reactdom js files from cdn in my .pug file, thinking that would help. They are there in view source when the app comes up, but no react components.

Comment: Are you using webpack or something similar?

Comment: @AndrewL. no, not using webpack. I'm trying to have as few moving parts as possible as I am just getting my feet wet with node and all the shiny new js libs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With things like NodeJS, they are *server-side*, not client-side. Meaning, they are not meant to be run in the browser. When you run your app locally, it uses Node locally so it's all fine, but in the browser the environment is different. To use Node in browsers see [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or some similar module loader.

Comment: So if, as a newbie, I "don't care whether something is server-side or client-side", but am in the mindset of "I just want to build a website using node technologies", I HAVE to use webpack? I didn't realise that. (ashamed). Can you have a server-side web app? If so, how would I make that work, I wonder. Going to try webpack and see if I can get anywhere with it...

Comment: @rstruck There are other alternatives: RequireJS, Browserify, etc.

Comment: I see. Jeez... web tech used to be so straightforward. OK. Well this has been enlightening I completely missed the point about node being server side (duh). I will accept this answer regardless of if I can get the other stuff working or not cos this is the mind-shift i needed..thx.